# How do I efficiently choose the terrain chunks to render based on the player position?

Tags: java, terrain-rendering, spatial-partitioning

Well, I have an array with all the terrains. How do I render them? I just add them to a List of terrains that are sent to the Renderer. There, every terrain of the list is rendered.

The problem is that if I add all the terrains of the array to the list (let's call it *toRenderList*), my computer explodes because of the number of terrains.

What I've tried to achieve it's to add to the list ONLY the terrains that are into a certain range. This is what I've done:

```
private static Terrain[][] terrains;
private List<Terrain> toRenderList;
private static final int NUMBER_CHUNKS = 3; //Number of terrains that are added to the list.

public void update(Player player){
    if(player.hasChangedTerrainPosition()){
        toRenderList.clear();
        for(int x = player.getTerrainPosition()[0]-NUMBER_CHUNKS; 
            x == player.getTerrainPosition()[0]+NUMBER_CHUNKS; x++){
            for(int y = player.getTerrainPosition()[1]-NUMBER_CHUNKS; 
                y == player.getTerrainPosition()[1]+NUMBER_CHUNKS; y++){
                terrainList.add(terrains[x][y]);
                System.out.println("Terrain "+x+","+y+" added!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just to clarify, the method player.*getTerrainPosition* returns a int[] with the current terrain coords in where the player is standing. The method player.*hasChangedTerrainPosition* returns **true** if the player has changed of  terrain.

The problem of this method is that for example if the player is in the position [0,0] it pops an error of ArrayIndexOutOfBounds because of a negative number.

I don't know if I've been specific. This is more basic Java than GamePrograming, but any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look at quad- or oct-trees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat all the chunks around player, as offsets (shown in one axis but applies for both):

`-3 -2 -1 0 +1 +2 +3` <- 7 offsets for 1 axis; for `x` * `y` that would be 49 offsets.

`0, 0` is the offset where the player is - the origin of "player space". `3, -2` might be roughly to the northeast or whatever, depending on your coordinate system setup, and so forth.

Now we add each of these coordinates to the player's actual position

`coords = player.getTerrainPosition() + offset`

Lastly, we need to ensure `coords` are in terrain array range(s). So for example if I was standing at `x=1` and was adding an offset of `-3` then `coords == (-2, y)`. We can't have any negative values like this, because then you get array indexing errors.

**To not show outside world bounds**, simply check for any negative coordinates and then do not use them to add a new terrain chunk! In this case any negative value, either `x` or `y`, is invalid.

**To wrap around on world bounds** for each axis `x` and `y`, modify `coords` one more time:

```
if (offset.x < 0)
    offset.x += terrainArrayWidth;
else
{
    if (offset.x >= terrainArrayWidth)
    {
        offset.x -= terrainArrayWidth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not clearing the list before you add new chunks. Tyy adding `terrainList.clear()` at the start of the update method.